# Is it possible to place an app in the Apple app store that is intended for select customers but not general public consumption?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

My company bosses want to create a native version of a currently web-based app that will be available to their existing customers (currently a few thousand).

They say it is imperative that the application be available for downloading from the app store.

However the app would only be of any use to customer who already have an account (and would be useless to anybody else who downloaded the app).

Is this actually possible to submit such a thing to the app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot restrict the intended users when distributing through the AppStore.

What you can do is apply for an [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/), though you'd be installing the app directly to the devices (requires physical presence of the devices).

You could also use a service like [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/), though their terms probably just allow deployment for testing purposes.

What I'd go for is getting the app to the AppStore anyway, as long as your app doesn't include  confidential content. You could advise in the description not to install the app unless they're your company's clients.

Comment: What @ninesided implies applies well to my last (and preferred) suggestion: if you include some kind of login which just your existing customers can access, you're restricting the usage of the app to just them

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of Apps in the App Store that where they are only usable if you are an existing customer. Look at all the banking related ones for example.